# grep for multiple filenames in a directory

Tags: bash, grep

I have a file (let's call it images.txt) - on each line is an image path. ie.

```
"images/dashboard/unit4A/lesson1.png"
"images/dashboard/unit4A/lesson2.png"
"images/dashboard/unit4A/lesson3.png"
"images/dashboard/unit4A/lesson4.png"
"images/dashboard/unit4A/lesson5.png"
```

etc.

I want to grep an entire directory (app) to see if each image path is mentioned anywhere in the HTML, CSS, or JS files in that directory.

I tried
grep -F -f images.txt app/*
but it complains that app/* has subdirectories, and also, it doesn't do exactly what I want (I don't need the actual lines that the images are found - I just need to know, for each image, whether it is present or not)

So a sample output might look like:

```
"images/dashboard/unit4A/lesson1.png" - found
"images/dashboard/unit4A/lesson2.png" - not found
"images/dashboard/unit4A/lesson3.png" - found
"images/dashboard/unit4A/lesson4.png" - not found
"images/dashboard/unit4A/lesson5.png" - found
```

Just returning a list of images that were not found would also be acceptable.

Is there a good way to do this using grep?

Comment: Not sure if I understand but can you try: `find app/ -type f | xargs grep -h -f images.txt | uniq | sort` which will search all subdirectories as well.

Comment: I updated w/ a sample output - does that make sense? I just want to know which images, in a long list of images, are not present in my project.

Comment: @Nicole add your OS (are you on OSX or linux or something else) as a tag so that we know which grep you are using.  Read up on the -R/-r flags and the -q flags for grep if available.

Comment: On OS X - the below solution seems to work, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `xargs` with **recursive** `grep` like this:

```
xargs -I % grep -ilR '%' /app/ --include={*.html,*.css,*.js} < images.txt
```

**EDIT** Based on edited question you can do:

```
while read -r pat; do
   printf "%s - " "$pat"
   grep -iqR "$pat" /app/ --include={*.html,*.css,*.js} && echo "found" || echo "not found"
done < images.txt
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem - this just prints out a list of files where it matched one of the strings (image paths) in the pattern. I need to know which images were not found.